# Using a data.frame as input for a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a custom function that takes in five inputs/parameters. The first two arguments are simply to filter a dataset. If I have a .csv file imported into a `data.frame`, I want to use each row (of the first two columns) to be the values for the function. i then would want to bind all the outputs together. For example, say I have the following data frame (`df`). The function would then be "Filter" below, and the data frame of arguments would be "List" below.

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"),c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),c(64,94,65,21,54,25,44,58,21,25,78,45)))
Filter <- function(V1, V2) {
    df <- df[df$V1 == V1 & df$V2 == V2,]
}
```

Using `Filter(V1 = 'A', V2 = 'A')` would yield rows 1 and 4.

I now have a data.frame that matches...
`List <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("A","A"),c("A","B")))`

And I am hoping I can use List to basic run:

`function(V1 = 'A', V2 = 'A')`

`function(V1 = 'A', V2 = 'B')`

and then bind them with an indicator column for which model it came from.

Comment: Hey Lindon, not sure exactly what your question is. Are you asking if it is possible to use data frames as an input? If so, absolutely, most objects in R can be used as inputs in a function. A function is essentially a wrapped up piece of code.

If you're asking us to write your solution for you, you may want to keep writing until you are stuck on a particular point. More than welcome to help you

Comment: Consider `Filter <- function(V1, V2, data) {...}`, then call with `Filter("A", "A", data=df)`. This helps keep the function *reproducible* and avoiding scope-breach; otherwise, if you ever load the data into a variable named other than `df` -- or have something else in `df` altogether -- debugging becomes frustrating. For functions like this, it is almost always best to have all "knowledge" inside the function be defined in the argument list, and using nothing that isn't explicitly passed to it.